# Registering Eclipse Headless build as Windows Service

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, windows-services, nssm

I currently developed an Eclipse application which also has a headless build available to integrate with some other application. We created a .exe for our application. What I need is when the installation of our application is completed the headless build should be register as window service. The headless build is started using a batch file which contains following :

```
set WORKSPACE=
java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -application myapplication.app.HEADLESSAPP -data %WORKSPACE% -noExit -isHeadLess
```

When we run this .bat file it starts our application in Non UI mode.

I tried following things so far:

1. Tried `sc.exe` command but this didn't work.
2. Then I converted my .bat file to `.exe` and then tried `sc.exe`(give error 1053) and `NSSM`(executable path always refer to [nssm.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M1zl.png) instead of my application).

So basically I need a way to to register this `.bat` or `.exe` file as windows service so that it launch my headless application.

**UPDATE :**

Tried this :

```
set SERVICE_NAME=TESTSERVICE
set SERVICE_TITLE="TESTSERVICE"

set ECLIPSE_DIR=%~dp0

"%~dp0TESTSERVICE.exe" install %SERVICE_TITLE% --Startup=auto --StartMode=java --StartImage="%ECLIPSE_DIR%eclipsec.exe" --StartPath="%ECLIPSE_DIR%\" ++StartParams="-noSplash -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -application com.eu.ales.hvac.ipm.headless.app.HEADLESSIPMDT -data \"%ECLIPSE_DIR%workspace\" -configuration \"%ECLIPSE_DIR%configuration\"" --LogPath="%ECLIPSE_DIR%\" --LogLevel="Error" --LogPrefix="service"
```

but getting this

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a headless Eclipse RCP application as Windows service I use successfully **[Apache Commons' *prunsrv.exe*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html)** ([download here](http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/)) for several years.

Step-by-step instruction to run Eclipse Infocenter (which is a headless RCP application and contained in all Eclipse IDE packages) as Windows service:

1. **Preconditions**:

   - A **Java** JRE or JDK is installed
   - An **Eclipse IDE** is installed, e. g. *[eclipse-SDK-4.7-win32-x86_64.zip](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.7-201706120950/download.php?dropFile=eclipse-SDK-4.7-win32-x86_64.zip)*
2. **Download *commons-daemon-1.0.15-bin-windows.zip*** from http://www.apache.org/dist/commons/daemon/binaries/windows/
3. Extract ***prunsrv.exe*** from root directory of the downloaded ZIP archive into your Eclipse installation directory
4. In the Eclipse installation directory create the file **`install_as_service.bat`** with following content:

   ```
   set INFOCENTER_PORT=8088
   set INFOCENTER_TITLE="Eclipse Infocenter"
   for %%i in ("%~dp0") do (set INFOCENTER_DIR=%%~dpi)
   set INFOCENTER_DESCRIPTION=Port: %INFOCENTER_PORT%, Location: %INFOCENTER_DIR%
   "%~dp0\prunsrv.exe" install %INFOCENTER_TITLE% --Description="%INFOCENTER_DESCRIPTION% " --Startup=auto --StartMode=exe --StartImage="%INFOCENTER_DIR%eclipsec.exe" --StartPath="%INFOCENTER_DIR%\" ++StartParams="-noSplash#-application#org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication#-data#\"%INFOCENTER_DIR%info_center_workspace\"#-configuration#\"%INFOCENTER_DIR%info_center_configuration\"#-vmargs#-Dserver_port=%INFOCENTER_PORT%#-Xms420m#-Xmx420m#-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" --StopMode=exe --StopTimeout=300 --StopImage="%INFOCENTER_DIR%eclipsec.exe" --StopPath="%INFOCENTER_DIR%\" ++StopParams="-noSplash#-application#org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication#-data#\"%INFOCENTER_DIR%info_center_workspace\"#-configuration#\"%INFOCENTER_DIR%info_center_configuration\""#-command#shutdown --LogPath="%INFOCENTER_DIR%\" --LogLevel="Error" --LogPrefix="service"
   ```
5. **Double-click `install_as_service.bat`**
6. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, enter **`services.msc`** and click *OK*

   - => The list of services should contain *Eclipse Infocenter*
7. **Start the service** *Eclipse Infocenter*
8. In a web browser open **http://localhost:8088/help/index.jsp**

   - => Eclipse Help should be shown in the web browser (similar to https://help.eclipse.org)

To uninstall the service, first stop the service and then run `prunsrv.exe delete "Eclipse Infocenter"`

Comment: If you remove or adapt _-application#com.example.rcp.product.application_ then it should work for your _sc.exe_: The service can be started, but the question is, how to shutdown your application: can you send a command (as in the example) or do you want to kill the process?

Comment: Oops, I thought your application is `sc.exe`. Change in the batch script `sc.exe` to `eclipsec.exe` or how your *.exe file is called (see my edits above).

Comment: Still a doubt... where should I put pluginCustomization option?? Under ++StartParams???

Comment: @howgler : tried your solution for achieving `java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar -pluginCustomization plugin_customization.ini -application myapplication.app.HEADLESSAPP -data %WORKSPACE% -noExit -isHeadLess` but unable to start service. See my update above.

Comment: @techie I added a step-by-step instruction to run Eclipse Infocenter which is a headless RCP application and contained in all Eclipse IDE packages. I hope this helps.

Comment: @tech Yes, stopping is broken. To fix it use [shutdown as Java command](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_help_setup_infocenter.htm) or use to start and stop the application `net.sf.helpaddons.rcp.product.webApplication` [of this project](https://sourceforge.net/p/helpaddons/code/HEAD/tree/). For your RCP application you have to find a way to send a shutdown signal.